# Calculate data rate using dpkt packet parsing for radiotap header

Tags: python, dpkt, radiotap

I need to calculate the data rate for a given packet, which is capture using pcapy. I use dpkt to get the radiotap header like this:

```
dpkt.radiotap.Radiotap(packet)
```

Now I need to access the data rate, and I assumed (wrongly) that Rate which is available on the Radiotap object was this. However, it is not or at least it just return 0 or 1.

So how can I calculated data rate from the info already available through `dpkt.radiotap.Radiotap`? or is the info actually in dpkt already, but have I just missed it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the packet data rate using radiotap.

```
pkt.radiotap.datarate
```